# Where does the code of WP7 Silverlight start from?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

In C# console applications windows applications we know that the code starts executing from the main function.

In WP7 silverlight there's no main function. If anybody can please tell me where the code starts executing from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App.xaml.cs
You'll find constructor App() which is like the main().
There is also severall methods that refers to specific application evenements (launching, activated, deactivated, closing ...)
this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211380.aspx) is a good started kit.